# Open which ports with UFW hotspot

Tags: ufw, hot-spot

I have a wifi hotspot with Ubuntu 22.04.

Without UFW enabled, my phone connects just fine and can browse the internet.
With UFW enabled, I could not connect.

So then in UFW, I opened domain (53), bootps (67/udp), bootpc (68/udp), 80, 443.
Now my phone connects to wifi with an assinged ip address, but it has no internet access.
Which port(s) do I need to open in UFW so that my phone can have internet access?

Do I have any ports open above I don't need to have open to allow devices to use my Ubuntu internet?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your UFW remove the `net/ipv4/ip_forward=1` ? Check UFW config in `/etc/ufw`

Comment: No, it just has ENABLED=yes and LOGLEVEL=low.